# Electron upload with progress

Tags: javascript, node.js, upload, axios, electron

I have an Electron app which is able to upload **very big files** to the server via HTTP in renderer process without user input. I decided to use `axios` as my HTTP client and it was able to retrieve upload progress but with this I met few problems.

Browser's supported js and Node.js aren't "friendly" with each other in some moments. I used `fs.createReadStream` function to get the file but `axios` does not understand what `ReadStream` object is and I can't pipe (there are several topics on their GitHub issue tab but nothing was done with that till now) this stream to `FormData` (which I should place my file in).

I ended up using `fs.readFileSync` and then `form-data` module with its `getBuffer()` method but now my file is loaded entirely in the memory before upload and with how big my files are it kills Electron process.

Googling I found out about `request` library which in-fact is able to pipe a stream to request but it's deprecated, not supported anymore and apparently I can't get upload progress from it.

I'm running out of options. How do you upload files with Electron without user input (so without file input) not loading them in the memory upfront?

P.S. on `form-data` github page there is a piece of code explaining how to upload a file stream with `axios` but it doesn't work, nothing is sent and downgrading the library as one issue topic suggested didn't help either...

```js
const form = new FormData();
const stream = fs.createReadStream(PATH_TO_FILE);
 
form.append('image', stream);
 
// In Node.js environment you need to set boundary in the header field 'Content-Type' by calling method `getHeaders`
const formHeaders = form.getHeaders();
 
axios.post('http://example.com', form, {
  headers: {
    ...formHeaders,
  },
})
.then(response => response)
.catch(error => error)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve this and I hope it will help anyone facing the same problem.

Since `request` is deprecated I looked up for alternatives and found [got.js](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got) for NodeJS HTTP requests. It has support of `Stream`, `fs.ReadStream` etc.

You will need [form-data](https://github.com/form-data/form-data#readme) as well, it allows to put streams inside `FormData` and assign it to a key.

The following code solved my question:

```js
import fs from 'fs'
import got from 'got'
import FormData from 'form-data'

const stream = fs.createReadStream('some_path')

// NOT native form data
const formData = new FormData()

formData.append('file', stream, 'filename');

try {
    const res = await got.post('https://my_link.com/upload', {
        body: formData,
        headers: {
            ...formData.getHeaders() // sets the boundary and Content-Type header
        }
    }).on('uploadProgress', progress => {
        // here we get our upload progress, progress.percent is a float number from 0 to 1
        console.log(Math.round(progress.percent * 100))
    });

    if (res.statusCode === 200) {
        // upload success
    } else {
        // error handler
    }
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Works perfectly in Electron renderer process!

Comment: Is there any limitation as far as file sizes go on this?

Comment: @CoryKleiser Didn't figure out any. I used this approach for a production app and the size of files our users upload is pretty big, we talk about over 1 GB sized zip files and so far not reports about not being able to upload due to file size